# Using sqlalchemy on_conflict_do_update with a condition on the update

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy's `on_conflict_do_update` function but with a condition on the update.

The idea is when new data comes in, we try to insert unless that primary key already exist. Then we will do an update BUT only if the date_column is from a later date than what is currently in the db. I understand I'll probably need to do some additional stuff with the actual date fields but I'm not sure how to add that condition in there. Has anyone had similar experience with this and was successful?

Currently, I have something like this which doesn't quite work at the condition part:

```
def upsert_last_calc_month(model: Any, data: Dict, prim_keys: List):
    insert_stmt = insert(model).values(data)
    do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        index_elements=prim_keys,
        index_where=model.date_column < data.get("date_column"),
        set_=remove_key(data, "created_at"),
    )
    return do_update_stmt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want `where` in this case.  The use of `index_where` is kind of nuanced but it seems to only affect which range of index_elements to check for conflict.

[where param](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Insert.on_conflict_do_update.params.where)

Here is an example I kludged together, I wouldn't take the datetime handling verbatim.  This is using `1.4.43` and seems to meet the  conditions:

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    DateTime,
)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

from pytz import timezone as pytz_timezone


def utc_now():
    """
    Only use directly in other low-level code, otherwise use the NowService.
    """
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc)


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)


class Calculation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "calculations"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # @NOTE: default and onupdate I think are python-level constructs
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=utc_now, onupdate=utc_now, nullable=False)
    date_column = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=utc_now, onupdate=utc_now, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def remove_key(d, key):
    return dict((k, v) for (k, v) in d.items() if k != key)

def upsert_calc(model, data, prim_keys):
    insert_stmt = insert(model).values(data)
    do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        index_elements=prim_keys,
        # Only if collected data is more recent than stored data..
        # @NOTE: What happens if source date_column  is NULL?
        where=model.date_column < data.get("date_column"),
        set_=remove_key(data, "created_at"),
    )
    return do_update_stmt

with Session(engine) as session:
    original_value=5
    today = utc_now()
    stmt = upsert_calc(Calculation, dict(id=1, date_column=today, value=original_value), (Calculation.id,))
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()
    stmt = upsert_calc(Calculation, {"id": 1, "created_at": today, "date_column": today - timedelta(days=5), "value": original_value-5}, (Calculation.id,))
    print (stmt)
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()
    print (session.query(Calculation).filter(Calculation.id == 1).first().value)
    assert session.query(Calculation).filter(Calculation.id == 1).first().value == original_value
    stmt = upsert_calc(Calculation, {"id": 1, "created_at": today, "date_column": today + timedelta(days=5), "value": original_value+5}, (Calculation.id,))
    print (stmt)
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.commit()
    assert session.query(Calculation).filter(Calculation.id == 1).first().value == original_value + 5
```